# vue js, how to pass an array in a template?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I just want to pass an array, or dict into a vue template:

```
 Vue.component('step', {

  props: ['data'],
  template: `
      <span> {{data}} {{typeof(data)}}</span>
  `
})
```

in html:

```
 <div id="app">
     <step data="['tefdfxt', 'Cats']"></step>
 </div>
```

Is evaluated as a string where it should be an array:

```
  ['tefdfxt', 'Cats'] string
```

My question is: How can you pass an array in html attribute in a way that's not evaluated as a sequence of string? The documentation didn't helped me.
Of course, I tryed {{}}, and all the parser invocation. Didn't work. Always evaluated as string.

### edit:

I need to add v-bind to the attribute in order to be evaluated as object:
https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-pass-array-in-child-component-as-a-prop/3584

So replace `data="['tefdfxt', 'Cats']"` by `v-bind:data="['tefdfxt', 'Cats']"`

Comment: If your edit contains the solution, please add it as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Based on your edit for future readers, you should replace `data` by `v-bind:data`:

```
<div id="app">
  <step v-bind:data="['tefdfxt', 'Cats']"></step>
</div>
```